# combine two jq filters into one

Tags: jq

How jq filter combines the filter outputs? Following jq not generates output.json with respective input arg value ('jack').

### input.json

```
{
"key1": "",
"key2": ""
}

 jq --arg input "$username" \
          'if .key1 == "<value1>"
                 then . + {"key1" : ($input) }
          else . end' input.json |
          'if .key2 == "<value2>"
                 then . + {"key2" : ($input) }
          else . end'  >  output.json
```

### output.json

```
{
"key1": "jack",
"key2": "jack"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter you are evidently trying to write is:

```
      if .key1 == "" then . + {"key1" : $input } else . end
      | if .key2 == "" then . + {"key2" : $input } else . end
```

This can be simplified to:

```
      if .key1 == "" then .key1 = $input else . end
      | if .key2 == "" then .key2 = $input else . end
```

You might also like to consider the following approach:

```
      def update(f): f |= (if . == "" then $input else . end);
      update(.key1) | update(.key2)
```